# Is there an updated accurate list of retailers who accept Bitcoin from Canadians?

Tags: canada

I'm new to Bitcoin and I wanted to know which retailers/hotels would accept Bitcoin as a form of payment from Canadians. If a site accepts Bitcoin as a form of payment does that mean they accept it from every country or just specific countries though they might accept credit card as a form from every country.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking 2 questions here..

1) list of retailers/hotels: try this site https://spendbitcoins.ca/

2) bitcoin is borderless. if they accept it, they accept it. now that's not to say a geo-located website might accept btc on their american (.com) site but not the british version (.co.uk), as overstock do. but that's a business decision, not a property of crypto currencies. think of it this way: if a business accepts it, they have a wallet address you can send money to, as long as you have a wallet too. doesn't matter where in the world you are. kind of like email.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [AirBitz business directory](https://airbitz.co/search?term=&location=Canada) actively maintains a curated list of merchants who accept Bitcoin, including merchants in Canada. They try to be as complete as possible, scraping data from multiple sources on a weekly basis. Each entry is hand-checked for completeness and correctness, so there should be very few false positives.

Answer (score -1):

LAMASSU BTM's are everywhere. Watch out though, because they charge at least 5% on all transactions.